# How can I clear a timer started with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, mouseover, clearinterval

I am trying to make my image move when I mouse-over it and then have it keep moving for 3 seconds before stopping.  I can get it to move, but not stop.  Any ideas?  Here is my code segment:

```
var time = setInterval(timer, 300);

onEvent("image3", "mouseover", function() {
  var x = getXPosition("image3");
  var y = getYPosition("image3");
  while ((getXPosition("image3") = x && getYPosition("image3") = y)) {

  }
});

function timer() {
  setPosition("image3", randomNumber(0, 250), randomNumber(0, 250), 100, 100);
  clearInterval();

}
```

Comment: You have to ask yourself questions like: How do you tell when 3 seconds has elapsed? How do you stop the timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) takes 1 argument - the intervalID corresponding to the timer to be cleared.

> #### intervalID
>
> The identifier of the repeated action you want to cancel. This ID was returned by the corresponding call to [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)</sup>

Pass the variable `time` to the call to clearInterval():

```
clearInterval(time);
```

See this demonstrated below.

```js
var time = setInterval(timer, 300);
var startTime;

function timer() {
  if (startTime === undefined) {
    startTime = new Date();
  } else {
    diff = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
    console.log('timer() - elapsed time: ', diff);
    if (diff >= 3) {
      console.log('clearing interval');
      clearInterval(time);
    }
  }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval</sub>

Comment: Great - if you believe this is the best solution, please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). For more information, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also, if you believe it is useful, consider giving it an [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (you will need 15+ reputation first).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the interval to clear when using `clearInterval`:

```
clearInterval(time);
```